# How to implement multiple models in multiple projects (assemblies)

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, clean-architecture

I have three models in three different assemblies (DLL):

1. `Students` ==> for `Student` model
2. `Classes`  ==> for `ClassRoom` model
3. `Teachers` ==> for `Teacher` model

Model classes:

```
// first assembly 
public class Student
{
    public int Id;
    public string Name;
    public List<Teacher> Teachers;
}

// second assembly 
public class ClassRoom
{
    public int Id;
    public string Name;
    public List<Student> Students;
}

// third assembly
public class Teacher
{
    public int Id;
    public string Name;
    public List<Student> Students;
    public List<ClassRoom> Classes;
}
```

How can I reference these three different assemblies to each other? (I fall in a circular dependency)

What is the clear way to migrateDB?

Please note that, all of these models reside in different assemblies.

I am using .NET Core 6.0 & EF Core 6.0

Comment: You can't. Why do you have these classes in a separate assembly?

Comment: It should be possible.  If you imagine that you work in a Bank or in a Big company, then you can understand what I mean. There are a lot of models in different assemblies, and your task is to use these different models from each other interchangeably.

Comment: Well you tried and it didn't work did it? These models/classes are clearly domain joined so they should be in a single assembly.

Comment: No, I just give an example and try to find out or break down the problem.
This is an example to demonstrate the idea, have you heard about The Dependency Inversion Principle?

Comment: Perhaps the way out would be to use interfaces - IStudent, IClassRoom, ITeacher - in the Common assembly.

Comment: I don't see any relevance to the dependency inversion principle here. It also doesn't dictate every class should be in a separate assembly.

Comment: @DavidLibido See please https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XydkF1AVbYE&t=753s&ab_channel=CodingTutorials

Comment: You *may* have the classes in different assemblies. Clearly the discussion got on a wrong track here. *but* I think your problem with circular dependencies is unrelated to assemblies. You have many-to-many relationship between `Teacher` and `Student`, which requires definition in `DbContext`. Does it work in a single assembly? If it *does*, please post `DbContext` class as well

Comment: WHAT? I am saying it is not possible to add assemblies, the IDE prevents me to add DLL to each other, Student refers to teacher and teacher refers to student, VS IDE prevents me to import DLL because "circular dependencies"  so why you need DbContext, I can't understand why!  I am still one step back before DBMigration.